# How to stream over RTMP on Android?

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtmp, flash-media-server

I'm trying to play video file on a remote server. Video format is flv and server is Flash Media Server3.5.

I'm going to connect to server over RTMP and to implement the palyback of video file using Android Media Player.

Really,is it possible? Any help is my pleasure.

Comment: hello, i am also facing problem in Rtmp streaming, have solved this problem?

Answer (score 4):

http://www.aftek.com/afteklab/aftek-RTMP-library.shtml

I found this one, but haven't had much luck, there are very few docs and after jigging it to try and support Video (no examples as i can see) i found that the core method RtmpStreamFactory.getRtmpStream(); failed.

This one has also cropped up, but i haven't looked at this yet.

http://code.google.com/p/android-rtmp-client/

It looks like that for me i'll be looking at getting the media server to deliver rtsp instead and this is supported by android. You may also find that later versions of Android i.e. 3> support rtmp.

Comment: Just wanna confirm this, does android >3 support rtmp ?

Comment: I thought it did, but i've checked this page and it doesn't specifically say it does. http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: RTSP is supported however, you might be able to change your server to use that instead perhaps?