# Android: how to stream video

Tags: android

I am programming android client that would show video from web camera in real time. The issue is that I get this stream over RTMP protocol. It seems that nobody knows an easy way to do that.

On stackoverflow I have found just unsolved question about that [How to stream over RTMP on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006043/how-to-stream-over-rtmp-on-android), but now may be someone knows the answer. All help would be appreciated.

P.S. 
I want to support Android 2.3 >

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use VLC for android [sources](https://github.com/videolan/vlc) or use some intermediary server (ffmpeg, avconv) to convert RTMP to RTSP